# Why does this minimal RNN code throw a type error for a type never used?

Tags: python, theano

I'm trying to implement a minimal recurrent neural network example in `theano`. I expected the following python script to print a 10-by-20 matrix representing a hidden state sequence.

```
# import packages/functions
from theano import shared, scan, function, tensor as T
import numpy as np

# declare variables
X = T.dmatrix("X")
Wx = shared(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (10, 20)))
Wh = shared(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (20, 20)))
b = shared(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (1, 20)))

# define recurrence function
def recurrence(x_t, h_tm1):
    return T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(h_tm1, Wh) + T.dot(x_t, Wx) + b)

# compute hidden state sequence with scan
ht, _ = scan(fn = recurrence, sequences = X,
             outputs_info = np.zeros((1, 20)))

# define function producing hidden state sequence
fn = function([X], ht)reshape((1,3))

# test function
print fn(np.eye(10))
```

Instead, it returns the error:
    `TypeError: Cannot convert Type TensorType(float64, 3D) (of Variable IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:}.0) into Type TensorType(float64, (False, True, False)). You can try to manually convert IncSubtensor{Set;:int64:}.0 into a TensorType(float64, (False, True, False)).`

This is especially confusing since, as far as I can tell, none of my variables are 3-tensors!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the code the question's code: the `reshape((1,3))` at the end of the `fn =` is invalid and appears to have been added in error. The code runs when this element of that line is simple deleted. The remainder of this answer assumes that edit is as intended by the question author.

I have not reproduced the stated error. This may be because I am using the bleeding edge version of Theano. It's quite possible the error message for this situation has been changed in the most recent versions of the code. However, the syntax error in the code above suggests another possibility: the question code is not actually the code that produced the error pasted into the question.

Using the edited code, and the latest version of Theano, I get the error

> TypeError: ('The following error happened while compiling the node', forall_inplace,cpu,scan_fn}(Shape_i{0}.0, Subtensor{int64:int64:int8}.0, IncSubtensor{InplaceSet;:int64:}.0, , , ), '\n', "Inconsistency in the inner graph of scan 'scan_fn' : an input and an output are associated with the same recurrent state and should have the same type but have type 'TensorType(float64, row)' and 'TensorType(float64, matrix)' respectively.")

This is similar in spirit to the question's error, but refers to a mismatch between a matrix and row vector; there is no reference to a 3-tensor.

The simplest change to avoid this error is to change the shape of the `b` shared variable.

Instead of

```
b = shared(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (1, 20)))
```

use

```
b = shared(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (20,)))
```

I would also recommend doing the same for the initial value of `h_tm1`.

Instead of

```
outputs_info = np.zeros((1, 20))
```

use

```
outputs_info = np.zeros((20,))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll make the suggested changes and see if the code runs on our server. The code snippet is not the exact code that produced  the error - I initially pasted the code up until the scan which is where I got the error when I ran the script line-by-line, but the snippet looked like a stub so I added the print line to make it a complete minimal example. This seemed like a good idea at the time, but I can see now why it might not have been.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is because theano wrap the output_info into unsuitable variables. For instance `outputs_info = np.zeros((3, 20))` will be wrapped into `TensorType(float64, matrix)`. But for the dim equals 1, theano autonatically braodcasts the dim, so `outputs_info = np.zeros((1, 20))` will be `TensorType(float64, row)` since the first dim is infered broadcastable.

A solution is `outputs_info = T.unbroadcast(T.zeros((1,20)), 0))`, this makes sure it wrapped as matrix.

```
# import packages/functions
from theano import shared, scan, function, config, tensor as T
import numpy as np

# declare variables
X = T.tensor3("X")
Wx = shared(np.asarray(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (10, 20)), dtype=config.floatX))
Wh = shared(np.asarray(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (20, 20)), dtype=config.floatX))
b = shared(np.asarray(np.random.uniform(-1.0, 1.0, (1, 20)), dtype=config.floatX))

# define recurrence function
def recurrence(x_t, h_tm1):
    print h_tm1.type, x_t.type
    return T.nnet.sigmoid(T.dot(h_tm1, Wh) + T.dot(x_t, Wx) + b)

# compute hidden state sequence with scan
ht, _ = scan(fn = recurrence, sequences = X,
             outputs_info = T.unbroadcast(T.zeros((1,20)), 0))

# define function producing hidden state sequence
fn = function([X], ht)

# test function
print fn(np.eye(10,10,dtype=config.floatX).reshape(10,1,10))
```